# Jquery flexslid click on div and show a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.porslider > .slides > li > div > ul > li').click(function() {
        var which = $(this).index();
        $('#big').find('div').hide().eq(which).show();
    });
});
```

When I click on a li item, there wil showing up a div. This is working. But not when I put this in a flexslider. My HTML look like this.

```
<div class="flexslider porslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <div>
                <ul class="porimages ulpor">
                    <li><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                    <li class="mr"><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                    <li><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                    <li class="mr"><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                    <li><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>                
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <ul class="porimages ulpor">
                    <li><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                    <li class="mr"><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                    <li><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                    <li class="mr"><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                    <li><a><img src="por_small/piWD00001.png" alt="" height="142" width="142"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>                
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="big">
    <div><img src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
    <div><img style="opacity: 0.5;" src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
    <div><img style="border: 2px solid red;" src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
    <div><img style="opacity: 0.1;" src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
    <div><img style="border: 2px solid blue;" src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="por_big/piWD00001.png" /></div>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
#big div {
display: none;
}
```

Is there an easy way that he is also see the second slide? Now he only see the first five thumbnails, but what I want is more slides. So, when people go to the second slide they wil also see the same image but bigger. How can I use this script on more slides?

Thanks!

Comment: For Best Practice use max 3 selectors...like in your case use `porimages>li` this would be easy for you.

Comment: But I cannot slide then. My page has to many picture's. I want put it in the flexslider. Is this possible?

Comment: Put your code in jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4KhUb/3/ Thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Here is a example what I want. http://s23.postimg.org/86tfdkdi3/example.png The problem that I have is he only see the first three thumbnails (three images) the last three he didn't see and he doesn't show the big one.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4KhUb/4/

Just try this to begin, and see if it works... i think Flexslider wraps something in your HTML that make your (ugly) selectors unable to work.

```
$('.porimages > li').click(function() {
    var which = $(this).index();
    $('#big').find('div').hide().eq(which).show();
});
```

OR

```
$('.porslider li li').click(function() {
    var which = $(this).index();
    $('#big').find('div').hide().eq(which).show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But is still not working. Here is a example what I want. http://s23.postimg.org/86tfdkdi3/example.png The problem that I have is he only see the first three thumbnails (three images) the last three he didn't see and he doesn't show the big one.